# Italian: is there an authoritative word frequency list?

Tags: reference-request, italian

I'm having difficulty finding a good frequency list for the Italian language (lemmas, not including inflected word forms). Anyone know if there's some research or website or institute where I could find a somewhat authoritative one? Thanks

Comment: You need to be more specific. What do you consider a "word": Lemmata, i.e. underlying dictionary forms, or each inflected form counted separately, like *ragazzo* and *ragazzi* being two distinct words? Do you also want to include function words, like *la* or *di*? And last but not least, the frequency of a word will depend on its context of usage: A law code will contain different words than colloquial speech. Also, how many words should your list contain, and which format should the frequency be given in (an absolute number of occurences in certain text, a relative percentage, ...)?

Comment: I'm looking for a frequency list to study, so it should not include inflected or conjugated forms, just infinitives and one form for words with gender. The problem is a lot of list are not like this and manually converting would be a huge pain.

Comment: This information helps. I could try to automatically make such a list from a corpus, if I find a good corpus for Italian (most of such resources are newspaper articles, would that be okay?) and if I know a little more about the required contents and format. What about function vs. lexical words? How long should the list be? What about the format of the frequencies? I can't promise yet that I will find something appropriate, but I can try to if you give me some more information. However, the list that @Jeremy Needle linked looks quite good already.

Comment: Hi Lemontree, the list below is unusable for study, so if you could make one that would be great! I'm looking for a list that I can systematically study to build vocabulary, I'm thinking around 3000 most common words with just one entry for each verb (no conjugated or any other forms) and also one entry for each adjective and noun (no plurals, gender derived forms). Newspaper articles or anything is great. I have no specific format required, just human readable, Thanks!

Comment: The library I was hoping to make the task very easy unfortunately doesn't have a corpus for Italian included; I found a set of annotated corpora that would also legally be useable for non-commercial use [here](http://www.di.unito.it/~tutreeb/treebanks.html) but I'd have to put some work in figuring out how to properly process the data format which I probably won't have the time for, I'm sorry.

Comment: However, after taking a closer look at the list that Jeremy Needle linked to (which also seems to be quite well made after having done a little research), he is right that it should be possible to transform the list to suit your needs: It seems like the table in fact already contains the lemma forms (I think this is the sixth column), so you could group all lines by lemmata, sum up the frequencies of all inflected forms belonging to that lemma and then re-order the list by the newly computed lemma frequencies. This should all be doable in Excel or so with a little work.

Comment: It's even easier. The seventh column ("dom_lemma_freq") seems to contain the frequency of the corresponding lemma ("dom_lemma"), so you'd only need to focus on these two columns, remove all duplicate and unwanted lines (like punctuation or <unknown> forms), re-sort the list by this freq and there you have your list of the several thousand most frequent words, even with the corresponding part of speech in case you want to include that information for your vocabulary studying. If you are willing to spend half an hour for editing this table to suit your needs, I think this one is pretty perfect.

Comment: This is probably too late for the OP, but if all you want is a roughly comprehensive list of common Italian word for self study, Tullio de Mauro (an important Italian linguist) compiled one: it's called *Nuovo vocabolario di base* and can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkcyo53m15ktbnp/nuovovocabolariodibase.pdf?dl=0) (see [here](https://www.internazionale.it/opinione/tullio-de-mauro/2016/12/23/il-nuovo-vocabolario-di-base-della-lingua-italiana) for a description of the project)

Comment: In response to @lemontree's Jul 3, 2016 at 21:41 message, here's what I did:
Save http://crr.ugent.be/subtlex-it/subtlex-it.csv to local drive.
Excel -> New Blank workbook. Data -> Get Data From Text/CSV. Import subtlex-it.csv with File Origin set to "65001: Unicode (UTF-8)". Transform Data. Save.
Copy data in columns dom_lemma and dom_lemma_freq into vi. Run commands %g/<unknown>/d and %g/@card@/ (plus other line deletes as you wish, e.g. deleting those with punctuation marks). Save as tmp.txt.
On Linux: sort -k2 -n -r tmp.txt | uniq > subtlex-it-lemma-sorted.txt

Comment: [follow-up to the msg above] The reason I have to do data transformation is that the file on the website has an encoding problem. E.g. line 6 shows the word as Ã¨ (instead of è). I communicated with Dr. Crepaldi, the author. Confirmed that the correct encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

For many languages, SUBTLEX is considered a good source for realistic frequencies. There is an Italian version, SUBTLEX-IT, available at http://crr.ugent.be/subtlex-it/; (Crepaldi, Keuleers, Mandera, & Brysbaert, 2013).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this list is not useful for study is it has separate entries for all conjugations, etc. I'm looking for a list that's ready for vocabulary study. I appreciate your response though.

Comment: Ah, it's good that lemontree asked about lemma vs. wordform then. You should alter the question to reflect this new requirement. Note that you can convert from wordform stats to lemma stats (but not the reverse) with a little effort.

Comment: Thanks for Jeremy Needle's recommendation. My Google search seems to confirm that Dr. Crepaldi et al's SUBTLEX-IT is widely used. To user9324: As lemontree suggested, you just need to view the columns of lemma and lemma frequency. I just posted the steps you need to do. For your convenience, I temporarily posted the result to http://yong321.freeshell.org/liw/subtlex-it-lemma-sorted.txt

Answer (score 3):

Frequency lists extracted from the WaCky corpora. Lists of words and lemmas are provided, sorted by frequency.

itWaC (Italian)
itWaC: a 2 billion word corpus constructed from the Web limiting the crawl to the .it domain and using medium-frequency words from the Repubblica corpus and basic Italian vocabulary lists as seeds.

http://wacky.sslmit.unibo.it/doku.php?id=frequency_lists