# big english word frequency list

Tags: english, resource-request, words

I'm in need of English 100,000 frequency word list.
I hope you tell me about a free option (if available) or an inexpensive one.

Comment: This answer https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/italian-is-there-an-authoritative-word-frequency-list/31001#31001 has a link that provides also an English word frequency list (besides Italian and German)

Comment: If you have enough text in ASCII, it's simple to make your own frequency lists with Unix utilities.